# Exchange 2010 Autodiscover URL

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010, autodiscovery

hope somebody can help me as I'm banging my head against the wall with this one! I've read and researched as best I can but cannot find a solution.

I have an Exchange 2010 server. The active directory domain is example.com and all my users are like this: first.last@example.com.

However, I've set the URL in IIS for Outlook Web Access to https://exchange.example.net. (Notice it's a .NET tld), because I have site-wide SSL certificate for *.example.net.

This is my desired set up. It works great.

However, Autodiscover is causing me a problem in Outlook 2010 clients. About 30 seconds after opening outlook and after the connection to Exchange is established (successfully), I  get a certificate warning telling me the certificate name does not match.

It pops up twice, first for autodiscover.example.com and then exchange.example.com.

I need to change the URLs to autodiscover.example.NET and exchange.example.NET.

PLEASE can somebody help me - it's driving me to despair!

Thanks,

Simon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a ExchangeManagmentShell (Powershell with Exchange Extension) and issue this command:

*Get-ExchangeCertificate  |select -ExpandProperty CertificateDomains*

Can you see your domainname in the output?

Comment: Hi @TimPe, thanks for your response. In the end the Windows Azure virtual Machine I was running crashed and I ended up starting again anyway. This time, I got all the domain stuff right first time! So I never got chance to figure it out in the end, but thanks for your help anyway.